# I need help with this regex pattern

Tags: php, regex, string

Hi I have a problem with my regex pattern:

`preg_match_all('/!!\d{3}/', '!!333!!333 !!333 test', $result);`

I want this to match !!333 but not !!333!333. How can I modify this regex to match only a max length of 5 characters - two ! and three numbers.

Comment: "match only a max length of 5 characters - two ! and three numbers". You mean in any order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the easiest and most descriptive way to do this is with negative lookaheads and lookbehinds.

See:

```php
preg_match_all('/(?<![^\s])!!\d{3}(?![^\s])/', '!!333 !!333!!333 !!333 test !!333', result);
```

This says: match anything of the form !![0-9][0-9][0-9] which doesn't have anything other than a space in front or behind it. Note that these lookaheads/lookbehinds aren't matched themselves, they are "zero-width assertions", they are thrown away and so you only get "!!333" etc in your match, not " !!333" etc.

It returns

```php
[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => !!333
            [1] => !!333
            [2] => !!333
        )

)
```

Also

```php
preg_match_all(
    '/(?<![^\s])!!\d{3}(?![^\s])/', 
    '!!333 !!555 !!333 !!123 !!555 !!456 !!333 !!333 !!444 !!444 !!123 !!123 !!123!!123',
    $result));
```

returns

```php
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => !!333
        [1] => !!555
        [2] => !!333
        [3] => !!123
        [4] => !!555
        [5] => !!456
        [6] => !!333
        [7] => !!333
        [8] => !!444
        [9] => !!444
        [10] => !!123
        [11] => !!123
    )
```

That is, all but the last two which are too long.

See [Lookahead tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: Why is it match the last set (!!123!!123) in `!!333 !!555 !!333 !!123 !!555 !!456 !!333 !!333 !!444 !!444 !!123 !!123 !!123!!123!!123 !!123!!123` It should not match `!!333!!333`

Comment: It's not. It's matching the `!!123 !!123` before the last two invalid entries.

Comment: Updated to match one of your original comments. From `'!!333 !!555 !!333 !!123 !!555 !!456 !!333 !!333 !!444 !!444 !!123 !!123 !!123!!123'` it matches everything but the last `!!123!!123` which seems to be exactly what you want :).

Answer (score 6):

```
/^!!\d{3}$/
```

You need the anchors `^`, that match the beginning of a string and `$` for the end. Its like saying: "It *must* begin at the start of the string and it *must* end at the end of it." If you omit one (or both) the pattern allows arbitrary symbols at the beginning and/or the end.

Update

As I found out in the comments the question was very misleading. Now I suggest to split the string before applying the pattern

```
$string = '!!333!!333 !!333 test';
$result = array();
foreach (explode(' ', $string) as $index => $item) {
  if (preg_match('/^!!\d{3}$/', $item)) {
    $result[$index] = $item;
  }
}
```

This also respects the index of the item. If you dont need it, remove the `$index` stuff or just ignore it ;)

Its much easier then trying to find a pattern, that fulfill  your request all at once.

Comment: When I do this it does not match anything at all

Comment: @Rob: Cannot reproduce `preg_match_all('/^!!\d{3}$/', '!!333', $result);` .... Or maybe you want the string `!!xyz` _within_ a longer one? Then your example works fine, because it matches `!!333` (they exists 3 times, thus it matches 3 times). Maybe you are looking for `preg_match()` instead of `preg_match_all()`?

Comment: I want it to match all of these except the last one because the last one is more than 5 characters long: `!!333 !!555 !!333 !!123 !!555 !!456 !!333 !!333 !!444 !!444 !!123 !!123 !!123!!123`

Comment: @Rob: AAAAHHH, they are separated by a whitespace and you want every single entry to match the pattern! You should have mentioned it ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
^!!\d{3}$
```

You need to anchor your pattern.

If you want to match a string with !!333 in it, you may want something like:

```
(^|\s)!!\d{3}($|\s)
```

With further explanation we can have a further refinement:

```
(^|\s)!!\d{3}(?=$|\s)
```

Which will not capture the trailing space allowing multiple matches in the same line to match one after another.

Comment: This does not match anything?

Comment: @Rob: That matches the string "!!333"  If you want to match a string with " !!333 " in it (including "!!333") then see my edit.

Comment: @Rob: You need to further explain what it is you are trying to do, what you want to match, and what you do not want to match.

Comment: The regex matches only every other set in `!!333 !!555 !!333 !!123 !!555 !!456 !!333 !!333 !!444 !!444 !!123 !!123 !!123` How to make it match all of those?

Comment: @Rob: Set up the regex to not capture the trailing space.  See my edit.